# Facebook PHP SDK new scope item added but no data

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, scope, facebook-login

i am developing a facebook app in the canvas of facebook
i have set the login with facebook and it works like a charm
later, i added the scope values,
how can i re-ask my visitors to give me permissions to those

[resetting the client access token in the developers section did not do the trick]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you they have the permission, and if not, send them to a new login url asking for the permission.

Off the top of my head:

```
try
{
    $perms = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
    $perms = false;
}

if( !isset( $perms['data']['user_work_history'] ) )
{
    $new_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'=>array('user_work_history'), /* you should only have to request the new permission, but can include them all */
        'redirect_uri'=>YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
    ));
}
```

Comment: i had :scope' => 'user_email,user_birthday,user_website,publish_actions,
then i added this :
'scope' => 'user_email,user_birthday,user_website,publish_actions,user_work_history',
but i can not make the user re authorize this extra request

Comment: I've updated the answer to better suit your needs based on that comment... are you sure the user has not already authorized the permission and just has no work history in their profile?

Comment: imagine the user has already granted my app with the previous scope(A,B for exemple)
after that i added an item to the scope (A,B,C)
i can not access his "C" and when he opens the app, he is not notified to grant me access to that added "C" scope